Unpivoting data in SQL from JSON
This is a follow up to this question: Possible to "unpivot" in SQL when ingested from JSON.
Let's say I have the following SQL table with data that was incorrectly inserted from a JSON document:
X1AB_name     X1AB_age        Y2AL_name       Y2AL_age
"Todd"        10              "Brad"          20

I would like to un-pivot the result based on the prefix (what is before the _ in the column name). Is it possible to do this with dynamic SQL? The answer I want to get is:
 id              name         age
 "X1AB"          "Todd"        10
 "Y2AL"          "Brad"        20


Is it always X1AB and Y2AL? Or do you, unrelated, have many many columns and only a single row?

if it is only one table (you know all column names), then the fastest and simplest way is generate a Select query with Union

@ThomA yes, there could be 1000 "ids" -- things like X1AB, Y2AL, Z3AB, ...etc.

If it's just the 4 columns, or the prefix is static, then this is simply achievable by unpivoting. Though you could use UNPIVOT, like PIVOT, the operator is quite restrictive. You are better off using VALUES to unpivot your data:
SELECT V.id,
       v.name,
       v.age
FROM dbo.YourTable YT
     CROSS APPLY (VALUES(N'X1AB',X1AB_name,X1AB_age),
                        (N'Y2AL',Y2AL_name,Y2AL_age))V(id,name,age);

If the prefixes could be anything, and you effectively have 10's (100's?) of columns and a single row, then you need to do a little more. Though you could use dynamic SQL, I don't actually see the need here. Instead you could actually use FOR JSON to unpivot the data, and then use OPENJSON to help you re-pivot the data. Again, I don't use the (restrictive) PIVOT operator, and use conditional aggregation. So this ends up with something like this:
SELECT V.id,
       MAX(CASE V.subkey WHEN N'name' THEN OJ.value END) AS name,
       MAX(CASE V.subkey WHEN N'age' THEN OJ.value END) AS age
FROM (SELECT *
      FROM dbo.YourTable YT
      FOR JSON PATH, WITHOUT_ARRAY_WRAPPER) J(JSON)
     CROSS APPLY OPENJSON (J.JSON) OJ
     CROSS APPLY (VALUES(LEFT(OJ.[key],NULLIF(CHARINDEX('_',OJ.[Key]),0)-1), STUFF(OJ.[Key],1,NULLIF(CHARINDEX('_',OJ.[Key]),0),'')))V(id,subkey)
GROUP BY V.id;

The VALUES at the end is used to avoid repetition of the LEFT and STUFF expressions.

what if you don't know the actual ids, for example, if there are 1000 and you just know it's the "prefix in the column name" ?

Then you use the bottom solution, @David542 , for "If the prefixes could be anything..."

ah, ok, that's pretty tricky then, and the PIVOT/UNPIVOT are all but useless here then. Thanks for the answer, and pretty neat usage of the CROSS APPLY in your answer -- cheers!

PIVOT/UNPIVOT are, like I mention in the answer, pretty restrictive. You can't, for example, use 2 different aggregate functions (such as COUNT and SUM) in a single call to PIVOT, however, with conditional aggregation is trivial. Conditional aggregation and a VALUES table construct are far better options; which I make use of both in the above, @David542 . Not to mention the syntax, in my opinion, is much simpler for them compared to PIVOT/UNPIVOT.

data
CREATE TABLE mytable(
   X1AB_name VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL  
  ,X1AB_age  VARCHAR(30)  NOT NULL
  ,Y2AL_name VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL
  ,Y2AL_age  VARCHAR(30)  NOT NULL
);
INSERT INTO mytable
(X1AB_name,X1AB_age,Y2AL_name,Y2AL_age) VALUES 
('Todd','10','Brad','20');


you can use Pivotand Unpivottogether to get the desired result
select *
from 
(
select 
PARSENAME(REPLACE(indicatorname,'_','.'),2) 'id',
PARSENAME(REPLACE(indicatorname,'_','.'),1) 'name2',
indicatorvalue
from mytable
unpivot
(
  indicatorvalue
  for indicatorname in ([X1AB_name]
      ,[X1AB_age]
      ,[Y2AL_name]
      ,[Y2AL_age]
      )
) unpiv
) src
pivot
(
  max(indicatorvalue)
  for name2 in ([name], [age])
) piv;

dbfiddle
